# Como aumentar o espaço entre os itens de um navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Desenvolvendo uma aplicação vi que em dispositivos com resolução maior os itens ficam muito junto, desejo praticidade, é assim que aplicativos mobiles devem ser, nada de botões muito pequenos, isso dificulta a vida do usuário, como podem ver na foto nem parece ter pouco espaço assim, mas usando realmente ficou apertado, desde já agradeço.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mesa"
            android:icon="@drawable/silverware_variant"
            android:title="@string/stPedidoMesa"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_entrega"
            android:icon="@drawable/delivery"
            android:title="@string/stPedidoEntrega" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_esperando"
            android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_system_clock"
            android:title="@string/stPedidoEsperando" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_buscar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_transfer_within_a_station_black"
            android:title="@string/stPedidoBuscar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_comer"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/map_marker"
            android:title="Comer"/>
    </group>
</menu>`

Comment: Aqui estão as medidas recomendadas pelos padrões do Material Design para um Navigation Drawer: https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html. Normalmente o componente NavigationView já é uma simplificação criada para atender nativamente esses padrões, então em teoria não deveria ser necessário alterar nenhuma medida do mesmo.

Comment: O colega @MárcioOliveira já citou corretamente, mas cada caso é impar então, o melhor para isso seria voce por tudo em um constraint layout, nele voce tem maior controle sobre as medidas e até com a disposição dos componentes no design

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver o que vou fazer aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Se voçê quiser aumentar o ícone basta ir em dimen i alterar com o código:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```